# How to change the id of clicked image

Tags: css, angular, ionic4

I want to change the id of selected image on click. Currently, clicking one image will **affect all** the images with [id]="available". How can I change for **specific image.** Here is my html

```
    <ion-row>
    <ion-avatar *ngFor="let seat of row1.seats; let i=index;" id="item- 
    {{i}}">
    <ion-label>{{seat.label}}</ion-label>    
    <img *ngIf="seat.booked===true" src="assets/st.png" id="booked"> 
    <img *ngIf="seat.booked===false" src="assets/st.png" 
    [id]="available" (click)="selectedSeat(seat.id)">
    </ion-avatar>
   </ion-row>
```

Here is ts.

```
available = "available";

  selectedSeat(id) {
    this.available = "selected";
  }
```

css:

```
  #available {
    background-color: cornsilk;
  }
  #selected {
    background-color: #614056;
  }
```

Comment: keep an array with same size and update based on index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setAttribute()` of `Renderer2` and template reference like following:

In template, add `#myImg` to `img` tag:

```
<img *ngIf="seat.booked===false" src="assets/st.png #myImg (click)="selectedSeat(myImg, seat.id)">
```

In component (.ts) file, inject `Renderer2` and use it in `selectedSeat` method:

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2){}

selectedSeat(seletctedSeat: ElementRef, id) {
    this.renderer.setAttribute(seletctedSeat.nativeElement, 'id', 'selected');
}
```

**!BUT!**

I think assigning `id` attribute is not the right way to do it. ID should be **unique** by nature, so you are assignin **same ID to multiple elements**. This sounds wrong. I think you should change CSS class if you only want to change styling but not applying any logic (like doing something with selected seat) with following:

In .ts file:

```
selectedSeat(seletctedSeat: ElementRef, id) {
    this.renderer.addClass(seletctedSeat.nativeElement, 'selected');
}
```

In CSS:

```
.selected {
    background-color: #614056;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

You can create an array and push selected ID's to it. Then check if the array includes the `seat.id`:

In template:

```
<img *ngIf="seat.booked===false" src="assets/st.png" 
    [ngClass]="selectedSeatList.includes(seat.id) ? 'selected' : 'available'" (click)="toggleSelection(seat.id)">
```

In component (.ts) file:

```
selectedSeatList: Array<number> = [];

toggleSelection = (seatID) => {
    if(this.selectedSeatList.includes(seatID)){
       this.selectedSeatList = this.selectedSeatList.filter(id => id !== seatID);
    }else{
       this.selectedSeatList.push(seatID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to change the `background-color` for an `ngFor`-created element with an index, when that index is selected through the `selectedSeat()` function.

If this is accurate, I would say to ignore the element's `id` entirely and use `class` instead.

You could start by using your `selectedSeat()` function to accept the template element's index as well as `seat.id`, then change your `available` variable to something like `currentlySelectedSeat` to the currently selected `ngFor` element's index:

```
currentlySelectedSeat = 0;  // <-- default to first index (if you wish)
selectedSeat(seatId, index) {
  if (index) {  // <-- basic check
    this.currentlySelectedSeat = index;  // <-- assign id
  }
  // do whatever else with seatId
}
```

If you slightly alter your css to define `classes` instead of `ids` like this:

```
.available {
  background-color: cornsilk;
}
.selected {
  background-color: #614056;
}
```

..you could then use a ternary in an `ngClass` and structure your template like this:

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-avatar *ngFor="let seat of row1.seats; index as i;">  // <-- id not necessarily needed. index still assigned to i, just written differently
    <ion-label>{{seat.label}}</ion-label>    
    <img *ngIf="seat.booked===true" src="assets/st.png" class="booked">  // <-- unless there will only ever be one of these images, use class instead of id
    <img *ngIf="seat.booked===false" src="assets/st.png" 
      [ngClass]="currentlySelectedSeat === i ? 'selected' : 'available'"  // <-- *this line clarified below
      (click)="selectedSeat(seat.id, i)">  // <-- expand function to accept template index as well.
  </ion-avatar>
</ion-row>
```

***Clarified ngClass template line:** this is the same as writing:

```
if (available === i) {  // <-- if the variable named available's value is the same as the index which was passed through selectedSeat() on click
  return 'selected';  // <-- give ngClass a string which corresponds to .selected
} else {
  return 'available';  // <-- give ngClass a string which corresponds to .available
```